# Reversing a string in iOS

Tags: ios

I am writing code which should reverse a string. When I run the following code it throws an error:

```
- (NSString*) reversingName:(NSString *)myNameText
{
   NSString *result;
   int len = [myNameText length];
   NSMutableString *reverseName = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:len];
   for(int i=len;i>0;i--)
   {
     [reverseName appendFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[myNameText characterAtIndex:i]]];
   }
   result = reverseName;
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this sample code :

```
NSString *name = @"abcdefghi" ;
    int len = [name length];
    NSMutableString *reverseName = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:len];

    for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        [reverseName appendFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[name characterAtIndex:i]]];

    }

    NSLog(@"%@",reverseName);
```

Comment: `[reverseName appendFormat:@"%c",[name characterAtIndex:i]];` is already suffice.

Answer (score 9):

The `for` loop line  should be as follows:

```
for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
```

So your method should be

```
- (NSString*) reversingName:(NSString *)myNameText
{
    int len = [myNameText length];
    NSMutableString *reverseName = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:len];
    for(int i=len-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        [reverseName appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[myNameText characterAtIndex:i]]];
    }
    return [reverseName autorelease];
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I thought I'd throw another version out there in case anyone's interested.. personally, I like the cleaner approach using NSMutableString but if performance is the highest priority this one is faster:

```
- (NSString *)reverseString:(NSString *)input {
    NSUInteger len = [input length];
    unichar *buffer = malloc(len * sizeof(unichar));
    if (buffer == nil) return nil; // error!
    [input getCharacters:buffer];

    // reverse string; only need to loop through first half
    for (NSUInteger stPos=0, endPos=len-1; stPos < len/2; stPos++, endPos--) {
        unichar temp = buffer[stPos];
        buffer[stPos] = buffer[endPos];
        buffer[endPos] = temp;
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithCharactersNoCopy:buffer length:len freeWhenDone:YES];
}
```

I also wrote a quick test as well to compare this with the more traditional NSMutableString method (which I also included below):

```
// test reversing a really large string
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString new];
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    int digit = i % 10;
    [string appendFormat:@"%d", digit];
}
NSTimeInterval startTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSString *reverse = [self reverseString:string];
NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - startTime;
NSLog(@"reversed in %f secs", elapsedTime);
```

Results were:

- using NSMutableString method (below) - "reversed in 3.720631 secs"
- using unichar *buffer method (above) - "reversed in 0.032604 secs"

Just for reference, here's the NSMutableString method used for this comparison:

```
- (NSString *)reverseString:(NSString *)input {
    NSUInteger len = [input length];
    NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:len];
    for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        [result appendFormat:@"%c", [input characterAtIndex:i]];
    }
    return result;
}
```

(NOTE: I don't have enough reputation points yet to vote or comment on answers so I'd appreciate if anyone could vote on this answer for me. I've been a long time reader but now want to start contributing more!)

Comment: You can even use XOR operation to make is faster(instead of allocating a temp variable each time)

Answer (score 1):

**Reverse a String in Swift 2.0:**

```
let string = "This is a test string."
let characters = string.characters
let reversedCharacters = characters.reverse()
let reversedString = String(reversedCharacters)
```

**The short way :**

```
String("This is a test string.".characters.reverse())
```

OR

```
let string = "This is a test string."
let array = Array(string)
let reversedArray = array.reverse()
let reversedString = String(reversedArray)
```

**The short way :**

```
String(Array("This is a test string.").reverse())
```